# Twitter Revoke 3rd-Party Permissions from iPhone & iPad iOS9

Tags: iphone, ipad, permission, twitter, 3rd-party

I know similar questions have been asked, but I couldn't find an answer to mine.  Is there any way to control Twitter permissions to third-party access from an iPhone / iPad?

I've tried to do it through the app & it seems impossible.  I've tried to do it from the website, but it seems constructed to keep users on the mobile site - from which it also appears impossible.

Is there a way to access the Twitter desktop site from a mobile iOS device (I'm just remembering that my *iPad* not *iPhone* had a desktop function in the recent upgrade.  I'll try that next ; )), or a way to access 3rd party permissions in the Twitter mobile app ... or any other app that makes up for this mobile access issue?

Thank you!  ; )

Joy

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with the desktop mode as it seems you cant do this from within the app.

As long as you can bypass that and go directly to www.twitter.com you should be fine.

To do that...
On Android, you hit the 3 dots near the address bar, scroll down, select "Request Desktop Site"

On an iPhone (currently at least!), Go to Twitter and scroll a little so you get the add new tab icon etc appear. Then, scroll across until you see the "Request Desktop Site" icon. Select it.

Now if you go to www.twitter.com and login you should be able to see the "apps" option in your settings and be able to revoke access.

I hope that helps!